# When drawing numbers from a population how to determine if the population shifts over time?

Tags: statistics

I administer technical interviews for a programming position. During the process I generate a single number 0-12 for each applicant's likelihood to succeed within the company. Over the last year I have an ordered list of 50 or so such numbers.

I suspect that over time, my judgment has changed and I am grading people easier (or harder) now than I was a year ago. What statistical analysis would I preform to get more information on this hypothesis? Since this is largely for my own curiosity, I would ideally like a tool that generates further insight rather than a simple hypothesis rejected/not rejected.

**PS.** Yes, I understand the limitations of generating a number for such a thing at all, and the general fallibility of "expert judgement". The entire reason for gathering these numbers to begin with is so that I can start using something other than *gut feel* for improving our process, but I am very conscious of the tendency to trust data like this too much.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to get a P value to test whether or not the change in the way your grading now vs. the way you were is statistically significant

andrewyaz [2:40 PM]
http://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/hypothesis-testing.aspx

Comment: There is no distinct line between now and then though. I could of course draw an arbitrary line, take the first and last third and do a t value test to check the probability of both belonging to the same population but that feels like it would be losing valuable information since it would leave out the middle third and also fail to account for the fact that measurements near each other in time are likelier to belong to the same population. In addition a p test could only ever give me a yes/no rather than any deeper insight